# having trouble writing htaccess redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having trouble writing redirect rules in my website's htaccess file.

Basically, i want to write two rules:

1 -  When i write the base URL, like `http://www.example.com`, i want it to automatically redirect the user to `http://www.example.com/someDirectory`.

2 - However, when i write `http://www.example.com/Admin`, i want it to redirect the user to `http://www.example.com/Admin`.

Here's what i've managed to do so far:

```
  # This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific subfolder
    Redirect http://www.example.pt http://www.example.pt/MainFolder
 # This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific subfolder
    Redirect http://www.example.pt/Admin http://www.example.pt/Admin
```

However this does not work... Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research i was able to find a solution to my problem. I'll leave it here, in case anyone's having the same problem:

```
#Rewrite everything to subfolder
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/MainFolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Admin
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ MainFolder/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

When there is no request for specific file or directory it will redirect you to your directory mention in rule and for the rest it will work without any rule.

Please check.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteRule ^ %{HTTP_HOST}/someDirectory [R,L]
```

Comment: can't get it to work properly! on your /someDirectory is where i put my /MainFolder, but do i need to specify anything else?

Comment: there is no error. it simply doesn't redirect me! the website is saudadebox.pt. whenever i enter saudadebox.pt or www.saudadebox.pt, i want it to redirect me to www.saudadebox.pt/SaudadeBox. And whenever i enter saudadebox.pt/Admin or www.saudadebox.pt/Admin, i want it to redirect me to www.saudadebox.pt/Admin